# Есть задачка по JS! Хотелось бы спросить правильное ли решение и какое еще может быть?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, global-variables

Условие:

Есть 3 переменные в которых хранится  размер составляющих 
  блочной модели в формате Npx, где N это целое число.
  Используя эти переменные, запишите в переменную totalWidth 
  общую ширину блока в формате Npx. 
  К примеру "сумма" '20px' и '30px' будет равна '50px'. 
  Если все верно, то в консоли будет выведена строка '125px'

Мое решение:

```
const padding = parseInt("30px");
const border = parseInt("50px");
const contentWidth =  parseInt("100px");

let totalWidth = `${padding + border + contentWidth}px`;

console.log(totalWidth);
```

Правильное или нет и какое еще может быть? Спасибо

Comment: вроде норм, только вы не учитываете, что padding и border скорее всего Х2

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev да, вы правы, автор не учел это)